# forcing download file with content-length mismatch

Tags: php, download, mismatch, content-length

I would like to use PHP to download a .csv file from a third party website. However, the `content-length` header is always set to `0` by the third party. Because of that, the downloaded file is always 0 bytes long and thus always empty. In reality the file size is about 14 KB.

I can download the file correctly by downloading it using the Google Chrome browser. Apparently, the browser ignores the header `content-length`.

Is there a solution in PHP to ignore the header `content-length` and download the complete file regardless of the value of that header?

This is the file I am talking about: https://lcps.nu/wp-content/uploads/covid-19.csv

At the moment I am using this function for downloading:

```
    public static function downloadRemoteFile( $remoteFile, $destinationFile ) {
        $handleSource = fopen( $remoteFile, 'r' );
        $handleDestination = fopen( $destinationFile, 'w' );
        $result = stream_copy_to_stream( $handleSource, $handleDestination );
        fclose( $handleSource );
        fclose( $handleDestination );
        return $result;
    }
```

As an alternative, I have tested `file_get_contents()` but that does not solve the problem.

Comment: Are you certain that `stream_copy_to_stream` copies the headers, too? I’ve never used that function, but my guess would have been that it would be up to `stream_get_meta_data` to handle  that. Also, can you show how you are invoking this?

Comment: I do not know whether `stream_copy_to_stream` reads the headers. I assume it does since it seems to stop downloading after seeing `content-length = 0`.

I invoke this function just by calling it 
`$result = FileUtils::downloadRemoteFile( self::LCPS_REMOTE_SOURCE_HOSPITAL_COUNT_CSV_FILE, 
                                self::LCPS_SOURCE_HOSPITAL_COUNT_CSV_FILE );`

Nothing fancy is goning on.

Comment: When I right-click that file from my Windows Chrome I also get a zero byte file. Maybe try the new URL? https://lcps.nu/wp-content/uploads/covid-19-datafeed.csv